# MySQL possible bug

Tags: mysql, syntax, boolean-expression

Imagine you have a table with 50000 rows and want to delete 5 entries based on the PK value.  The expected query might look like this:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 5 OR id = 10 OR id = 15 OR id = 20 OR id = 25
```

This works as expected.  However, if you're in a hurry and accidentally format it like this:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = 5 OR 10 OR 15 OR 20 OR 25
```

It will delete all 50000 rows.  Does anyone know if this is a bug?  If not I don't understand why it treats it like a delete all instead of return a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a bug in MySQL.

10, 15, 20 and 25 are truthy values. So when the `OR` is evaluated against one of them, the whole condition is true.

You should consider an `IN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, unlike standard SQL:

- `false` and the integer `0` are treated the same
- `true` and the integer `1` are treated the same
- any integer value other than zero is also treated as `true`

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/boolean-literals.html

Your expression is combining several terms as boolean conditions:

```
(id = 5) OR (10) OR (15) OR (20) OR (25)
```

Since all non-zero integers are treated as `true`, this ends up being like:

```
(id = 5) OR (true) OR (true) OR (true) OR (true)
```

And you should recall from high school math that `X OR true` evaluates as `true`.

Note that the your expression would also do something you don't expect in many other programming languages. Using integer as a series of boolean terms doesn't compare those integers to the operand of the first term.

Comment: Thanks, the reason it behaves that way then makes sense.  I definitely wish it wouldn't treat any integer as true but I know that now for the future.